# App with both SideDrawer and No Sidedrawer

Tags: nativescript-vue

I have a app working nicely with a sidedrawer, but would like to add pages without that menu.

The magic for launching a sidedrawer seems mostly in app.js:

```
new Vue({
     render (h) {
        return h(
          App,
          [
            h(DrawerContent, { slot: 'drawerContent' }),
            h(Home, { slot: 'mainContent' }    
    ]
        )
  }
  }).$start();
```

And we could launch a home page without that drawer:

```
         render: h => h('frame', [h(Twisty)])}).$start();
```

But how to launch the sidedrawer menu later, after viewing the drawer-less pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I may have been thinking about this wrong.

By making the 'menuless' page just another entry in DrawerContent.vue, and adding

```
android:visibility="collapsed"
ios:visibility="collapsed"
```

to that page's ActionItem, the page appears menuless. Then a nice

```
this.$navigateTo(Home);
```

gets us back to the regular sidebar navigation.

(I'd actually tried this before, and it was failing, but because I was calling YoutubePlayer in Preview, not for any sidebar related issue.)